# what is wrong in this query

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a table something like

```
class BulkStore(PresageBaseModel):
    store_key = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

But when I query on `store_key` it doesn't return anything

```
sk = 'agd2b3hhdWxhcjcLEhZwcmVzYWdlX2FwcF9jb2xsZWN0aW9uIhtwcmVzYWdlX2RlbW9fY29sbGVjdGlvbl9rZXkM'
print BulkStore.all().filter('store_key',sk).fetch(1)
```

output:

```
[]
```

but manual search gets the correct result

```
for bulkStore in BulkStore.all():
    if bulkStore.store_key == sk:
        print bulkStore
```

output:

```
BulkStore(key_id=849L, store_key=u'agd2b3hhdWxhcjcLEhZwcmVzYWdlX2FwcF9jb2xsZWN0aW9uIhtwcmVzYWdlX2RlbW9fY29sbGVjdGlvbl9rZXkM', name=u'collection_record_export')
```

What i may be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for this **[bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4262)** is that if a property is assigned a value which is already another db type it mysteriously takes the type of that value, e.g. in my BulkStore model store_key is a StringProperty but if I assign it a value which is TextProperty, store_key is stored as TextProperty not StringProperty which I have defined it to be and later on query on such properties doesn't work, so in db you can have entities some of which will be searchable and some won't be.

so never do this

```
bulkstore.store_key = some_entity.some_text_value
```

instead do this

```
bulkstore.store_key = str(some_entity.some_text_value)
```

This can be a very subtle bug to find in code :(

Answer (score 3):

In one of your examples, the string ends with a `.`, in the other, it doesn't.  These are not equal strings.

Comment: that was copy-paste error and was an example to show what is not working,  I am using same sk variable in two ways one works other doesn't?